# Pandas - Get column value counts as new columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

| Type | Status |
| --- | --- |
| typeA | New |
| typeA | Working |
| typeA | Working |
| typeA | Closed |
| typeA | Closed |
| typeA | Closed |
| typeB | New |
| typeB | Working |
| typeC | Closed |
| typeC | Closed |
| typeC | Closed |

I'd like to group the dataframe by the 'Type' field and get the count of each status as a column, like so:

| Type | New | Working | Closed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| typeA | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| typeB | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| typeC | 0 | 0 | 3 |

I'd also like columns for statuses that could exist (I have a list all possibilities), but may not be represented in the input dataframe, so the final result would be something like this:

| Type | New | Working | Closed | Escalate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| typeA | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| typeB | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| typeC | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 |

I'm able to get the counts per status by using:

```
closureCodeCounts = closureCodes.groupby(['type','status'],as_index=False).size()
```

I've also tried

```
closureCodeCounts = closureCodeCounts.groupby('type').value_counts()
closureCodeCounts = closureCodeCounts.unstack()
```

But nothing seems to come out right.

I'm pretty lost. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you share the sample data in dict as well?

Comment: @ShadabHussain Copy the table and then use `pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')` to read most tables people post on here.

Comment: Converting `Status` into a categorical will solve your problem here, it's designed exactly for such cases~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follows:

- Use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to reach the first stage of your desired output.
- For the second stage, I am assuming that the `list` you mention indeed contains *all* possible values. If so, we can apply [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to `axis=1` to add the missing possibilities as `columns`.
- As mentioned by [BeRT2me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11865956/bert2me) in the comments, we can use the `fill_value` parameter inside `df.reindex` to populate the new columns with zeros (instead of default `NaN` values).

```
possible_statuses = ['New','Working','Closed','Escalate']

res = (pd.crosstab(closureCodes.Type, closureCodes.Status)
       .reindex(possible_statuses, axis=1, fill_value=0))

print(res)

Status  New  Working  Closed  Escalate
Type                                  
typeA     1        2       3         0
typeB     1        1       0         0
typeC     0        0       3         0
```

---

An alternative approach to reach the first stage could be as follows:

- Use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.value_counts.html) and chain [`df.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html).

```
res = (closureCodes.groupby('Type')
       .value_counts()
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
       .reindex(possible_statuses, axis=1, fill_value=0))

print(res)

Status  New  Working  Closed  Escalate
Type                                  
typeA     1        2       3         0
typeB     1        1       0         0
typeC     0        0       3         0
```

This is, of course, pretty close to what you were trying to do in the first place (but you don't need the intermediate `closureCodeCounts`).

---

"Cosmetic" additions:

```
res.columns.name = None # to get rid of "Status" as `columns.name`
res.index.name = None # similar for `index`
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the 2nd method with groupby() did it for me!

Out of curiosity, do you know why 'type' shows up on its own line?

status  New  Opened  Working  Escalated
type
typeA   0.0     0.0      0.0        0.0
typeB  43.0     0.0      0.0        0.0
typeC   9.0     0.0      0.0        0.0

Comment: `Type` is the `index.name`. This happens because the *column* named `Type` has become the index. You can get rid of it in the same way as I've suggested above with `Status` (i.e. the name for the *columns*, since the actual columns consist of the original values in `closureCodes.Status`). Use `res.index.name = None` and it will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the pivot table to transpose your grouped Dataframe -

```
closureCodeCounts = pd.pivot_table(closureCodeCounts, values = 'size', index=['type'], columns = 'status').fillna(0)
```

And then similar to @ouroboros1 answer, reindex your Dataframe to add the missing columns.

```
possible_statuses = ['New','Working','Closed','Escalate']
result = closureCodeCounts.reindex(columns=possible_statuses, fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert `Status` to a categorical.

Then, we'll make a simple pivot table:

```
df.Status = pd.Categorical(df.Status, ['New', 'Working', 'Closed', 'Escalate'])

# Using a pivot table:
out = df.pivot_table(index='Type', columns='Status', aggfunc='size')

# Or, using a groupby:
out = df.groupby(['Type', 'Status']).size().unstack('Status')

# Or, making a crosstab:
out = pd.crosstab(df.Type, df.Status, dropna=False)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
Status  New  Working  Closed  Escalate
Type
typeA     1        2       3         0
typeB     1        1       0         0
typeC     0        0       3         0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val = df.groupby(['Type']).value_counts()
ax = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(val.axes[0])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=[0], columns=ax)
for i in range(len(val)): df.loc[0, ax[i]] = val[i]
```

| typeA |  |  | typeB |  | typeC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Closed** | **Working** | **New** | **New** | **Working** | **Closed** |
| 3.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 |